# Print the duplicate of a value in python

Tags: python

In the example below, I have two functions, a variable, and a for loop. The histogram function returns the number of times a character is repeated. The `has_duplicates` function returns if the string passed to it has a duplicate character or not. In the for loop, I want to test my functions. If the string of characters has a duplicate, it should print the str and the "has duplicates" string along with it, and if it doesn't have a duplicate, it should print the string and the "has no duplicates" string along with it.

When I run this code with the `test_dups variable, in the string "bookkeeper", it outputs that it has no duplicates, but that is not correct since it has three duplicate characters and the other string are doing will.

I was wondering what I should change in this code to get the expected output.

```
test_dups = ["zzz","dog","bookkeeper","subdermatoglyphic","subdermatoglyphics"] 

def histogram(s):
     d = dict()
     for c in s:
          if c not in d:
               d[c] = 1
          else:
               d[c] += 1
     return d 

def has_duplicates(str):
    value_of_dict = histogram(str).values()
    for i in value_of_dict:
        if i > 1:
            return True
        else:
            return False

for i in test_dups:
    if has_duplicates(i):
        print(i, "has duplicates")
    else:
        print(i, "has no duplicates")
```

Comment: What happens in `has_duplicates` if, for example, `value_of_dict` is the sequence `(1, 2)` ?

Comment: What happens if you add `"bookkeeperb"` to `test_dups`?

Comment: Look closely at `has_duplicates`: What happens if the very first bin in the histogram is `1`? How do you have to modify that function to do what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`histogram("bookkeeper").values()` returns `dict_values([1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1])`.  When you loop through those values you are returning a True if you encounter a a value greater than `1`. Since `1` is the first value you reach the else clause and return `False`.

Change

```
for i in value_of_dict:
    if i > 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

to

```
for i in value_of_dict:
    if i > 1:
        return True
return False # no value greater than 1 was found after looking at ALL values
```

You could also change it to

```
return any(i > 1 for i in value_of_dict)
```

Or you could check the length of the histogram against the length of the string. The histogram will be shorter if there are any duplicates.

```
def has_duplicates(str):
    return len(s) != len(histogram(str))
```

Another way to implement `histogram()` would be

```
from collections import Counter

def histogram(s):
    return Counter(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is the `has_duplicate` function.

If you go to the else block it will return `False`. However, you want to make sure that you look at each of them before returning.

An improved solution is given below:

```
def has_duplicates(str):
    value_of_dict = histogram(str).values()
    if max(value_of_dict) > 1:
        return True
    return False
```

Here you check if any of the letters appear more than once by using the maximum value between them. If that is greater than one, you return True else False.

Also, you are using a reserved keyword `str` for your function parameter. It is generally advised against using reserved keywords as variables.

Comment: *"However, you want to make sure that you look at each of them before returning."* It doesn't make a big difference if we're only talking about 26 letter counts, but you don't necessarily need to look at every one. As soon as you find even one value that's >1, you can return True. So it's possible to speed up a bit with `any` rather than `max` here.

Comment: @slothrop I was talking about the worst case, where the duplicate appeared last in the list. However, you are correct and `any` would definitely increase performance.